# Frequency distribution of array

Tags: c#

Write a program that allows any number of values between 0 and 10 to be
entered. When the user stops entering values, display a frequency distribution
bar chart. Use asterisks to show the number of times each value was entered.

I wrote this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numArrElement;
        Console.Write("How many number do you want to enter in array: ");
        numArrElement = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] numbers = new int[numArrElement];
        string inValue;

        for (int i = 0; i< numArrElement; i++)
        {               
            Console.Write("Enter your number between 0-10: ");
            inValue = Console.ReadLine();
            if(int.TryParse(inValue , out numbers[i]) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid data entry----0 stored");
            }
        }

        GetRepeatedValue(numbers);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    //Method
    public static void GetRepeatedValue(int[] num)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
        {
            int valueCnt = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < num.Length; j++)
            {
                if (num[j] == i)
                {                   
                    valueCnt++;
                }
            }
            if (valueCnt > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + " " + valueCnt);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't post assignments please.

Comment: I have problem with solving this question. I need help.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I assumed that. But you need to start to try to solve it on your own and post a *question* about a *specific* problem you're facing with it if it hasn't already been asked/answered. Your posts should also include a minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: My code is working except last part that I should print asterisks.

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to follow the requirements. It says they should be able to enter any number of values within the given range. I don't think you should be asking them or limiting them to a number of inputs. Consider keeping an array of integers that are keeping track of the number of times a given number is entered. You still need to be more specific about what exactly doesn't work about the code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will correct it.
The problem is after getting the number of times each value was entered, the result should be show by asterisks. 
For example if value of 2 was entered 3 times, I have to print 3 asterisks and so on.
I was stopped up to this part.

Comment: That would require a loop as opposed to simply printing the `valueCnt` wouldn't it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = new int[11]; //spec: valid values [0-10]

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number [0-10] or 'q' to quit and draw chart: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        var value = 0;

        if (inputIsValid(input, out value))
        {
            data[value]++;
        }
        else if (input.ToLowerInvariant() == "q")
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid number, pleae try again.");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(printASCIIChart(data));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static bool inputIsValid(string input, out int value)
{
    if (int.TryParse(input, out value))
    {
        if (value > -1 && value < 11)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private static string printASCIIChart(IEnumerable<int> data)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var counter = 0;

    foreach (var num in data)
    {
        builder.AppendLine($"[{counter:00}]: {new string('*', num)}");
        counter++;
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

The relevant part is `printASCIIChart` and the way to store the user's input.

The easiest way to store the data is simply using an array that keeps count of each number incrementing the counter in the corresponding index. Printing out the bar chart is pretty straighforward once your data is stored this way, simply using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx) handy `string` constructor.